# Configure Z Shell ohmyzsh theme font on MacOS Catalina

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'd like to use Oh My Z Shell `agnoster` theme

https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes#agnoster

[image]

in `.zshrc`

> ZSH_THEME="agnoster"

But after ohmuzsh installation , it look like some symbols are missing in default MacOS font for terminal. And `agnoster` says nothing about requirement for any specific font.

```
  ~/Workspaces/Java/project1   master 
```

[image]

P.S. Using MacOS Catalina

Comment: Just a guess: Maybe unsuitable font for your terminal?

Comment: Of course, it is matter of font. So if some theme uses some font, then it should ensure it is  installed in the system (or says it requires)

Comment: Who is "it"? You are the user of the Terminal application, and you configure the terminal and which font to use. If you need certain fonts, you should provide them. At best, you can contact the supporters of oh-my-zsh and ask for a recommendation of which font to use. Given the huge variety of fonts which come on the Mac, I don't think you need to install an additional one. Which one are you using now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. You need to download these fonts:

https://github.com/powerline/fonts

And then change your preference settings per the instructions at the bottom of the readme:

> iTerm2 users need to set both the Regular font and the Non-ASCII Font in "iTerm > Preferences > Profiles > Text" to use a patched font (per this issue).